# Laravel Eloquent relation echo the first value of the result set

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Order` modal like this

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderImage::class);
    }
}
```

And an `OrderImage` modal like this

```
class OrderImage extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

I can access the related images from `$order->images` variable, but how can echo a single field (`src` for example) of the first image of the resultset without a foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this as the following:

```
 $order->images()->first();
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is querying for the first image which is better if you don't have any already loaded.  If you have eager loaded the relationship already, it'd be better to use your existing collection with `$order->images->first()`.

Comment: Thank you. What would I have to do if I want to echo a particular field/property inside the first image array?